# Can I see all uploaded images on Imgur based on my anonymous api key?

Tags: imgur

Basically, I have done a lot of testing with imgur anon api uploading and didn't save the json data being passed back. Can I see the gallery of what was posted? Now that I think about it, if I can see images by api key, then I couldn't delete images based on that without the delete keys, but still curious if there is a way to see everything I have uploaded (or better yet delete).

Comment: The clue's in the name. You need to use the authenticated API for this.

Comment: @CasterTroy Stackoverflow is not for clues. It's for answers.